# Taking relative command line arguments... In Java

Tags: java, path, arguments, tilde-expansion

No I don't mean relative to project or working directory. I mean that the following command `java -jar myJar.jar ~/` should provide a string with `"/home/user"`... This doesnt seem to be working as expected. I am passing the argument in via eclipse's "Run Configurations" menu and am not sure if this is causing a problem. The same result comes from a Runnable Jar...
Its throwing a malformed URL exception... but URI doesnt like it either

Does anybody know a way to implement this functionality? Such that an argument `~/` is passed into `(String[] args)` as `"/home/user"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so much a Java issue as a shell issue.

The "tilde expansion" that replaces `~/` with `/home/user/` is performed by the shell (on Unix-like operating systems).  It looks like Eclipse doesn't do that expansion when using the "Run Configurations" menu, so you'll either have to specify `/home/user/` directly, or write some Java code to detect a leading `~` in a pathname argument and perform the expansion yourself.